# 3 item next to each other but on mobile 3 rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 items that i am showing with this code

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <i class="icon_set_1_icon-29"></i>Private/Group&nbsp;
    <i class="icon_set_1_icon-83"></i>8 hours&nbsp;
    <i class="icon_set_1_icon-52"></i>Morning Half Day
</div>
```

With this i can not get 3 different row on mobile.

And I try col system of bootstrap

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><i class="icon_set_1_icon-29"></i>Private/Group</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><i class="icon_set_1_icon-83"></i>8 hours</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><i class="icon_set_1_icon-52"></i>Morning Half Day</div>
</div>
```

And the result on mobile is ok but on normal view is not like i want.

result of bootstrap col system is like this 
[image]

I want to have this view on normal browser[image]
 and on mobile this view

[image]

How i can do that with bootstrap?

Comment: Please use rows and read the documentation > http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

Comment: i have tried that before not working

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I see no difference between your first 2 images other than the fact that your screenshots are different. Can you explain what's not the way you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need add css that clears the column in the desktop breakpoint

less:

```
@screen-md:                  992px;
@screen-md-min:              @screen-md;

@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { 
    .col-md-clear{
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-clear"><i class="icon_set_1_icon-29"></i>Private/Group</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-clear"><i class="icon_set_1_icon-83"></i>8 hours</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-clear"><i class="icon_set_1_icon-52"></i>Morning Half Day</div>
</div>
```